# jQuery hint plugin and problem with $_POST

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using [remy sharp's hint plugin](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/).

```
<input type="text" title="hint" name="names" class="input" />
```

But when I post the form without filling the fields, input still has

```
  $_POST['names'] = 'hint';
```

How can I prevent this issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : jQuery Code:

```
$(".input").hint();

$(".lSubmit").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post('form.php',decodeURIComponent($("#forms").serialize()) , function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
     });
 });
```

Comment: That's quite weird, looking at the plugins code and demo, it seems to remove the hint when the form gets submitted. Are you bypassing the forms default submit in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin removes the hint itself when the form the input is in gets submitted, unfortunately you are not submitting the form, but posting it via `$.post`.

The most simple way would probably to check the value(s) of the input(s) just before it gets submitted against its title, and clear it if they are the same:

```
$(".lSubmit").click(function(e){

   // clear inputs that still have the hint as value
   $('.input').each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
         $(this).val("");
      }
   });

   e.preventDefault();
   $.post('form.php',decodeURIComponent($("#forms").serialize()) , function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

Just add an if statement to your code:

```
if($_POST['names'] == 'hint' ) {
   //DONT USE IT!!
}
```